# centering multiple absolute divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a questions about centering multiple absolute div horizontally. I have a parent div that i s relative that contain four child divs. I want them to center evenly. Is there a way to center the four divs then add once? Or must I position them one by one? What I have now is when I position the divs absolute. They stack on top of each other, when they are centered.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post some of your code or a js fiddle so we can see the problem? cheers

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3w50gj28/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `div` for your sub `div`s and use `display: flex`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

boxes {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.eq {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 233px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>MyBMW Login</h3>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Emailadres">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="eq">
  <div class="box">
1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
3
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I had to delete `position: absolute`. If it's not what you want, please give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this, worked for me.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxes {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 233px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can also add align-items: middle; to the parent div, and use margin: 0 auto; to align stuff in the center

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't make this as absolute, these `.box` divs need to be relative, you can make the `.boxes` a "position absolute".

```
https://jsfiddle.net/DamianToczek/3w50gj28/4/
```

Make the .boxes absolute, the ID .box cant be absolute you always make a container that is absolute. If you want to make .box absolute, you need to give them another id like .box1 .box2 .box3, the best option is always a container that holds the "centered" items, the container is .boxes for you:

```
.boxes {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```